# gl_PointSize zero in WebGL

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, glsles

I have a vertex shader that sets `gl_PointSize = mix( 0. , 5. , step(foo,bar) );`. My mac with an Intel HD Graphics 5000, renders only the points that are 5, not the 0. Another mac with some kind of a radeon rendered the zeroes as if they were one.

I've read through the gl_PointSize and did not understand what is the desired behavior with `gl_PointSize = 0.;` and did not understand the bit about aliasing and rounding.

If I want to "hide" certain points, should I rely on `gl_PointSize = 0.;` to not even rasterize the points, or should i use something else?

Two things come to mind:

```
//frag

...
if( vSomeVarying < 0.5 ) discard; //but why even rasterize, and this is still like rendering all the points regardless of the discard?
...


//vert

if( someValue < 0.5 ){

  gl_Position.z = 2.; //should clip it?

}
```

Comment: seem like your second solution, setting the Z (or X or Y) outside of clip space, would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to "hide" certain points, should I rely on gl_PointSize = 0.; to not even rasterize the points, or should i use something else?

Use something else, because in [GLES 2.0.25](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) on p51:

> If the value written to `gl_PointSize` is less than or equal to zero, results are undefined.

Forcing the vert to be clipped works.